# ERREUR : <text> in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to import data into R.
When I submit

```
Dataset <- read.table("Data.txt",
       header = TRUE, sep = "\t", na.strings = "NA", dec = ".", strip.white = TRUE)
```

it works, but when I added `row.names = 1` and I submit

```
 Dataset <- read.table("Data.txt",
       header = TRUE, sep = "\t", na.strings = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = 1, strip.white = TRUE)
```

I get `ERREUR:<text>`

Comment: what is row.names=1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first instance works, perhaps the easiest way would be simply to :

```
`Dataset <- read.table("Data.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", 
                       na.strings = "NA", dec = ".", strip.white = TRUE)
rownames(Dataset) <- Dataset[, 1]
Dataset <- Dataset[, -1]`
```

And you should have the solution with the first column of `Data.txt` being the row names of `Dataset`